# Sustaining Internet access while changing my MAC address

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, internet-connection, mac-address

I have noticed whenever I change my MAC address, I loose internet access until my wifi re-connects. My question is, is there any way to avoid losing internet connection when changing my MAC address? Could being on ethernet be a potential solution?

Thanks to all of those who reply in advance.

Comment: This wreaks of being an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). The solution is to stop changing your MAC address. There's hardly any reasons for even change it _once_, let alone changing it regularly. What reason could you possibly have for constantly changing your MAC address?

Comment: @n8te I am trying to pen-test against some systems while exploiting how some websites identify unique devices. Hence, the lack of detail I have given in the OP.

Comment: MAC addresses work at layer 2. So they never leave your local network. “Websites” have no idea what your MAC address is.

Comment: @Appleoddity Interesting you say that. I have noticed that I can perform bot like activity on a site, get rate limited, and then resetting my MAC address reset's the rate limit. Not sure as to why if you make the claim website have no idea what the MAC address. I have tested this with other permutations as well.

Comment: @otterdog it’s not happening because of a MAC address. Something else is changing. Changing a MAC address almost always involves a change in IP address too. It could be any number of other identifying factors but it’s not a MAC address.

Comment: @Appleoddity So I have been reading more about how MAC addresses work at layer 2. However, I came across this piece of information: _In today’s networks, ARP, or Address Resolution Protocol converts a MAC address to a Layer 3 protocol address, such as an IP address_ ... Could this conversion have an affect in explaining why I am able to bypass rate limiting when I hop from one MAC address to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being on Ethernet might help. It depends how quickly your computer switches over to using the Ethernet connection once it loses wifi.

The reason you're losing Internet for a moment is because your MAC address is a vital part of "identifying" your device on the network through the ARP table. When you're "changing" you MAC address, you're not physically changing it. You're only spoofing it. Essentially, you're tricking the OS into thinking the NIC has the address you've applied to it.

The ARP table associates and IP address with a MAC address. When you spoof your MAC address, the mapped MAC address no longer matches with the IP address that is in the ARP cache. Your connectivity is restored once the ARP cache is up to date.

Even if you try the Ethernet option, you'll still possibly see a short interruption.

Comment: Thank you for a well worded answer.

Comment: You're right about the ARP cache having to expire, but... there's no "tricking the OS" about it, really. The OS **tells the NIC** what MAC address to use, and once you set a new address, it is _really_ being used, i.e. the driver writes it to the card's registers and the card treats it as its own address. (The value that's physically baked-in is only a "default", and in many cards [like AMD PCnet](https://wiki.osdev.org/AMD_PCNET#Card_registers_setup) it doesn't even participate in the network at all – it's actually the OS job to tell the card to use that baked-in address in the first place.)

Comment: @grawity depends on the NIC. I think most drivers allow you to change the MAC. However, if you're using a software tool, you're making the OS believe the NIC has the MAC address that you chose, without actually writing the address to the cards registers. For example, some software implementations of MAC spoofing simply write a value into the registry.

Comment: @DrZoo: It's probably true that some tools do not actually restart the interface to read the new address from registry, but even in that case, there's still no "making the OS believe" because the OS itself _doesn't use_ that value – the driver has to [read](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ndis/nf-ndis-ndisreadnetworkaddress) and apply it. The OS only believes what the driver tells it about the current and permanent MAC addresses during initialization. (It has to, because only the driver knows how to read the _original_ MAC address from the card as well...)